# regex with 'Named Capture Group' to catch a pattern or an alternate one

Tags: python, regex

I try to catch with one unique regex

```
either: ' PIC S9(17).'            # with 'S9(17)'      in Named Capture Group pic
either: ' PIC S9(13)V9(2).'       # with 'S9(13)V9(2)' in Named Capture Group pic
either: ' PIC S9(9)V9(2) COMP-3.' # with 'S9(9)V9(2)'  in Named Capture Group pic
either: ' PIC X(16).'             # with 'X(16)'       in Named Capture Group pic
```

with `r'\s*PIC\s+(?P<pic>\S+)'`
  I catch all but ' PIC S9(9)V9(2) COMP-3.'

with `r'\s*PIC\s+(?P<pic>\S+) COMP-3'`
  I catch only ' PIC S9(9)V9(2) COMP-3.'

This is my Python code:

```
import re
def get_pics(data, pic):
    base = r'^(?P<level>\d{2})\s+(?P<name>\S+)'
    end = r'\.$'
    pformat = "({})?"
    pattern = re.compile(base + pformat.format(pic) + end)

    for row in data.strip().split('\n'):
        re_match = pattern.match(row.strip())
        if not re_match:
            print(' => NOP:\n    ', row)
        else:
            match = re_match.groupdict()
            print('ok:', match)

data = """
   12 M-AR03-MONTANT-RDJ                 PIC S9(17).
   12 M-AR03-COMPTE-RDJ                  PIC X(8).
  09 M-N014-INC-CHARG-AMT-FSOL           PIC S9(9)V9(2) COMP-3.
  09 M-N014-CHARGE-TYPE-FSOL             PIC X(5).
"""
```

So we get:

```
>>> get_pics(data, r'\s*PIC\s+(?P<pic>\S+)')
ok: {'level': '12', 'name': 'M-AR03-MONTANT-RDJ', 'pic': 'S9(17)'}
ok: {'level': '12', 'name': 'M-AR03-COMPTE-RDJ', 'pic': 'X(8)'}
 => NOP:
       09 M-N014-INC-CHARG-AMT-FSOL  PIC S9(9)V9(2) COMP-3.
ok: {'level': '09', 'name': 'M-N014-CHARGE-TYPE-FSOL', 'pic': 'X(5)'}
>>>
```

or

```
>>> get_pics(data, r'\s*PIC\s+(?P<pic>\S+) COMP-3')
 => NOP:
     12 M-AR03-MONTANT-RDJ         PIC S9(17).
 => NOP:
        12 M-AR03-COMPTE-RDJ       PIC X(8).
ok: {'level': '09', 'name': 'M-N014-INC-CHARG-AMT-FSOL', 'pic': 'S9(9)V9(2)'}
 => NOP:
       09 M-N014-CHARGE-TYPE-FSOL  PIC X(5).
>>>
```

What is strange is that in https://regex101.com/ the `'\s*PIC\s+(?P<pic>\S+)'`
match for all 4 lines:

```
PIC S9(17).
PIC S9(13)V9(2).
PIC S9(9)V9(2) COMP-3.
PIC X(16).
```

If I try the @the-fourth-bird regex I get:

```
In [2]: get_pics(data, r'\bPIC (?P<pic>(?:[A-Z]\d*\(\d+\))+)[^.\r\n]*\.') 
   ...:                                                                                                                            
 => NOP:
     12 M-AR03-MONTANT-RDJ          PIC S9(17).
 => NOP:
        12 M-AR03-COMPTE-RDJ           PIC X(8).
 => NOP:
       09 M-N014-INC-CHARG-AMT-FSOL    PIC S9(9)V9(2) COMP-3.
 => NOP:
       09 M-N014-CHARGE-TYPE-FSOL      PIC X(5).

In [3]:
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want capturing group `pic` with those values and there should be at dot at the end present, you could make the pattern a bit more specific:

```
\bPIC (?P<pic>(?:[A-Z]\d*\(\d+\))+)[^.\r\n]*\.
```

- `\bPIC`  Word boundary, match `PIC` and space
- `(?P<pic>` Named group `pic`

  - `(?:` Non capture group

    - `[A-Z]\d*\(\d+\)` Match a char A-Z, opitonal digits and 1+ digits between parenthesis
  - `)+` Close group an repeat 1+ times
- `)` Close group `pic`
- `[^.\r\n]*\.` Match any char except a dot and newline 0+ times and match the trailing dot

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/NVpFSi/1) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/SJTRkh)

---

In your code, you don't have to make the group optional using `?` The pattern for the group `pic` already contains matching the ending dot so you could omit `end = r'\.$'`

Between the first and the second pattern, there are one or more spaces which you could match using `[^\S\r\n]+` which will match 1 or more times any whitespace char except a newline.

---

For example

```
import re
def get_pics(data, pic):
    base = r'(?P<level>\d{2})\s+(?P<name>\S+)'
    pattern = re.compile(f"^{base}[^\S\r\n]+{pic}$")
    for row in data.strip().split('\n'):
        re_match = pattern.match(row.strip())
        if not re_match:
            print(' => NOP:\n    ', row)
        else:
            match = re_match.groupdict()
            print('ok:', match)

data = """
   12 M-AR03-MONTANT-RDJ                 PIC S9(17).
   12 M-AR03-COMPTE-RDJ                  PIC X(8).
  09 M-N014-INC-CHARG-AMT-FSOL           PIC S9(9)V9(2) COMP-3.
  09 M-N014-CHARGE-TYPE-FSOL             PIC X(5).
"""

get_pics(data, r'\bPIC (?P<pic>(?:[A-Z]\d*\(\d+\))+)[^.\r\n]*\.')
```

Output

```
ok: {'level': '12', 'name': 'M-AR03-MONTANT-RDJ', 'pic': 'S9(17)'}
ok: {'level': '12', 'name': 'M-AR03-COMPTE-RDJ', 'pic': 'X(8)'}
ok: {'level': '09', 'name': 'M-N014-INC-CHARG-AMT-FSOL', 'pic': 'S9(9)V9(2)'}
ok: {'level': '09', 'name': 'M-N014-CHARGE-TYPE-FSOL', 'pic': 'X(5)'}
```

Comment: I see it working on regex demo but in my python code no line is matched. Can that be my `pformat = "({})?"` ?

Comment: @user3313834 Sorry for my late response. I have updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Given the limited example of yours, I can't see why the following is not enough:

```
r'\sPIC\s((?:(?:[SV]\d|X))?\((?:\d+)\))+( COMP-3)?\.'
```

There's no need, for instance, to use `\s+` if there's always only 1 space as in your example.

Similarly there's no reason not to use the literal `COMP-3` in the regex, if you don't tell us how that bit can vary (e.g. *It's `COMP-` followed by an integer number of any number of digits*? Ok, fine, use `COMP-\d+`).

Comment: `get_pics(data, r'\sPIC\s((?:(?:[SV]\d|X))?\((?:\d+)\))+( COMP-3)?\.')` get no match, probably something bad in my Python.re code

Answer (score 1):

I modified your base pattern to include whitespace at the end and crafted a different pattern for `pic`.

```
pat2 = r'(?P<level>\d{2})\s+(?P<name>\S+)\s+'
picpat = r'PIC\s(?P<pic>[^.\s]+)'
```

`picpat` matches anything after `'PIC '` till it gets to a dot or whitespace.

[image: Regular expression visualization]

I changed the function a bit using an f-string to combine it with the *pic pattern*, iterating over matches instead of lines.

```
def get_pics(data,pic):
    pat2 = r'(?P<level>\d{2})\s+(?P<name>\S+)\s+'
    pattern = f'{pat2}{pic}'
    #pattern = '{}{}'.format(pat2,pic)
    pattern = re.compile(pattern)
    for match in pattern.finditer(data):
        print(match.groupdict())


>>> get_pics(data,picpat)
{'level': '12', 'name': 'M-AR03-MONTANT-RDJ', 'pic': 'S9(17)'}
{'level': '12', 'name': 'M-AR03-COMPTE-RDJ', 'pic': 'X(8)'}
{'level': '09', 'name': 'M-N014-INC-CHARG-AMT-FSOL', 'pic': 'S9(9)V9(2)'}
{'level': '09', 'name': 'M-N014-CHARGE-TYPE-FSOL', 'pic': 'X(5)'}
>>>
```